# Combining two images from uiimageviews into one uiimage with correct positions

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, core-graphics

I have a view with two UIImageViews. The first uiimageview is a picture, which can be changed but is always at the same position. The second uiimageview contains a uiimage of a logo, this uiimageview can be resized, panned and rotated.

Both uiimageviews are set to Aspect Fit by the way.

When im done dragging and scaling the second uiimageview, i want to save these two uiimages, and draw one single uiimage. But in the new uiimage i need them to be positioned exactly as they were after i finished dragging and resizing the second uiimageview.

Im pushing this combined uiimage over to a new uiviewcontroller, which is called PreviewViewController. Here i want to show the uiimage in an imageview, and save it if the user presses yes.

**I almost got it working, but the x and y position is confusing me.
And there is another problem, when drawin the second uiimageview image onto the new image, its view mode looks like Scale to fill and it looks ugly.**

Heres my code

```
- (UIImage *)combineImages{

    UIImage *tshirt = self.tskjorteTemplateView.image;
    UIImage *logo = self.bildeView.image;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tskjorteTemplateView.image.size);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.tskjorteTemplateView.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
    [tshirt drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0, self.tskjorteTemplateView.frame.size.width, self.tskjorteTemplateView.frame.size.height)];
    [logo drawInRect:CGRectMake(bildeView.center.x - (bildeView.frame.size.width / 2) ,
                                bildeView.center.y - (bildeView.frame.size.height / 2), self.bildeView.frame.size.width, self.bildeView.frame.size.height)];

    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return result;
}
```

and its called here:

```
fullPreviewImage = [self combineImages];

WantToSaveViewController *save = (WantToSaveViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
save.delegate = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
save.previewImage = fullPreviewImage;
```